# pysnmp - how to fetch data from backend

Tags: pysnmp

I am using the example snmp agent provided by pysnmp for walking a table.  In the example provided, all data is fetched in the agent.*init* routine, which means that it is fetched once at startup, and cached.  I would like to fetch fresh data from the system every time  a 'get' or 'walk' request is received ....where in the example agent code would be a good place to do this?  Is there an example available for this?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get hold of the SNMP requests coming to your SNMP agent.

One way would be to subclass the `MibScalarInstance` class and define your own `getValue` method from which you could call your backend for actual fresh information. Here is [the example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html#implementing-scalar-mib-objects).

If your SNMP table is dynamic (e.g. its rows can come and go), make sure to assign your custom `MibScalarInstance` classes to their parent [MibTableColumn.protoInstance](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py#L827) so that new rows would be created from your custom `MibScalarInstance` derivatives.

Alternatively, you can abandon the whole pysnmp MIB subsystem and just interpret the OIDs you are getting from SNMP requests and building response OID-value pairs. Here is [the example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html#custom-mib-controller) of such approach.